# Loop through range, once value is found, copy cell value and everything under and move to next column

Tags: vba, loops, excel

This is my first post. I've been trying to teach myself excel VBA and it has been quite challenging.

Anyways I have been working on loops and ranges etc etc.

Here's my dilemma:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Move_Data()

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim result As String

result = "New Results"

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For i = 3 To LastRow
For j = 1 To LastColumn


If Cells(i, 1) = result Then
    j = j + 1
    Cells(i, 1).Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j)

End If


Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Little by little I have put the above together. Here's my question:

I am trying to look at all the values in column "A". Once "New Results" is found I want to copy not only this cell, but everything underneath it, to a column "J". Then find the string in column "B" and copy the range to column "K", etc.

So far the code finds "New Results" and moves it to column "B" which is expected since is the only code I have written. How can add another loop that will copy everything under "New Results" along with it and move it over to the new column. This way J will keep increasing and eventually I will have all the results broken down by columns.

Hopefully this makes sense.

Thanks all,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont have to loop through all the cells. Rather use the `Find() method`. It's more efficient I think.

```
Sub Move_Data()

    Dim rngFound As Range
    Dim intColLoop As Integer
    Dim LastColumn As Integer
    Dim result As String 'added in edit, forgot that, oops
    Dim intColPaste As Integer 'added in edit

    result = "New Results"
    LastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    With Cells
        'in case the result is not on the ActiveSheet, exit code
        If .Find(result) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

        '*****************Search all the columns, find result, copy ranges
        'search all the columns
        For intColLoop = 1 To LastColumn
            With Columns(intColLoop)
                'check if the result is in this column
                If Not .Find(result) Is Nothing Then
                    'find the result
                    Set rngFound = .Find(result)
                    'copy the found cell and continuous range beneath it to the destination column
                    Range(rngFound, rngFound.End(xlDown)).Copy Destination:=Cells(Rows.Count, 10 + intColPaste).End(xlUp)  'Edit : changed the "10" to "10 + intColPaste"
                    intColPaste = intColPaste + 1 'Edit : added counter for columns
                End If
            End With
        Next intColLoop 'proceed to next column
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I had a laugh a bit. :D  Unbelievable, how synchronized our answers were.

Comment: @BranislavKollár This is great however, the code found the data and moved the data to Column J. How can I break it down. For example:

I want the first instance of new results to have everything under it on Column J. Second instance and everything under Column K. Does this make sense?

Comment: I've edited the code to fit your needs. It could also be done by finding last column again, with `...End(xlToLeft)`.

Comment: Note, that the pasted columns will be next to each other. The first found range will be copied to column "J", next found range will be copied to column "K", etc. Even if some of the searched columns dont have the "result".

Answer (score 0):

Very well written for your first post, congrats!

```
Option Explicit
Sub Move_Data()

Dim SourceCol As integer
Dim DestCol As Integer
Dim LastRow As Long
'Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim result As String
Dim Addr as string

  SourceCol = 1       'Column A
  DestCol = 2         'Column B
  result = "New Results"

  LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

  set rng = ActiveSheet.Range(cells.Address).Find (What:=Result, LookIn:=xlValues, _
          LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
  While not rng is Nothing and Addr <> rng.Range.Address
  'If not rng is Nothing
    ActiveSheet.range(cells(rng.row, DestCol),cells(LastRow,DestCol) = _
            ActiveSheet.range(cells(rng.row,SourceCol), cells(LastRow,SourceCol))
  'End If
    Addr = rng.range.address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
    set rng = ActiveSheet.Range(cells.Address).Find (What:=Result, LookIn:=xlValues, _
          LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
  wend

End Sub
```

Adjust `SourceCol` and `DestCol` as needed.

That's untested and off the top of my head, so it might need a minor tweak. Use `.Find()` to find your text, then set your destination range = to what you just found.

As written, it will find one occurrence of `result`. If you have multiple occurrences of `result`, comment out/delete the `If...` and 'End If` lines, then uncomment the 4 lines that are commented & they'll loop through, finding them all.

Comment: Thank you. I am getting a Argument Not Optional on this line:

    rng.Range.Address

Comment: In that case, I presume you're using the `While` loop. I've fixed that line of code & updated to show the `While` loop.